# Can jQuery.data cause a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks, circular-reference

Would the following piece of code create a memory leak.

According to the jQuery documentation use of the `data` function avoids memory leaks. It would be useful to confirm whether the following is safe.

```
var MyClass = function(el) {
    // Store reference of element in object.
    this.element = $(el);
};

// Store reference of object in element.
$('#something').data('obj', new MyClass('#something'));
```

Comment: Why you dont save reference in global js object?

Comment: @ant_Ti I would like to have two way access. For example, in an event handler I would like to access `obj`, but I would also like to be able to access the element from `obj`.

Comment: I edited the question to remove mentions of circular references, since this example doesn't contain one. (Although it looks like it might)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obviously the code as it stands would take up extra memory as long as the DOM element is still connected to the DOM. But I'm guessing you're asking whether it would continue using extra memory after the DOM element is no longer in use.

**Update**: Thanks to Joey's answer (which he has since deleted), I spent some time reading up on [memory leaks in javascript](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/), and it appears my assumptions in the paragraph below are incorrect. Because DOM elements don't use pure garbage collection, a circular reference like this would normally prevent both the DOM element and the javascript object from ever being released. However, I believe the remainder of this answer is still correct.

<strike>Without a deep knowledge of how javascript engines implement garbage collection, I can't speak authoritatively on the topic. However, my general understanding of garbage collection makes me think that your code would be "safe" in the sense that after the `#something` element is removed from the DOM, the resulting `MyClass` object would only have a reference to an object that has no other connections. The graph algorithms of the garbage collector should be able to identify that the DOM element and its `MyClass` object are "floating in space" and unconnected to everything else.</strike>

Furthermore, jQuery goes out of its way to strip data and events that are associated with a given DOM element once it is removed from the DOM. From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/):

> jQuery ensures that the data is removed when DOM elements are removed via jQuery methods, and when the user leaves the page.

So assuming you use jQuery consistently, you would only have a one-way reference once the object is removed from the DOM anyway, which makes it <strike>that much easier</strike> possible for the garbage collector to know it can get rid of these objects.

So as long as you don't have something else referencing the `MyClass` object once the DOM element is removed, you shouldn't have a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it depends on the Javascritp engine.

You have have the question precisely enought to perform a test. I added a long string in the object and ran the potential leak in a large loop.

As a result, I don't think in leaks in IE8 nor in Chrome.

But I could not reproduce [these leakeage patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081410/does-use-of-circular-reference-incur-memory-leak) either.

Answer (score 0):

This can lead to a memory leak.
the theory of jQuery.data method may use A Data inner class to cache data for the dom element.

of course,when you remove the cache data,jQuery will unreference the data.
but the inner cache is a increasing array,when you you it ,it will go upon.

so ,in the end,there will be very big cache array,which will lead memeory leak.
In a long run web app,this may leak memory crash.

Answer (score -4):

The data attribute only stores string values.

Comment: In jQuery it can be any Javascript type including Array or Object.

Comment: @ant_Ti -- where does it say that in the doc?

Comment: [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) description says **value** The new data value; it can be any Javascript type including Array or Object.

Comment: @Neal see paragraph starting with "The `jQuery.data()` method allows us to attach..." (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) My concern was that the element reference is stored within the object itself.

Comment: @Lea Hayes, you misunderstand the documentation.  The data reference in not stored in the object, it is stored globally and associated with the dom node.  See my updated answer.

Comment: @Neal, the docs never says that it has to be a string.  Look at the big grey box with the function prototype: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/